# how to solve "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, httpwebresponse, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am downloading image by using asp.net c# then my code goes to catch block and show me error like this

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

when i click my download button it takes me in this and i directly goes in catch section and i got this error in `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` function

```
protected void ImageDownloadClick_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

    string stoneid = HdnStoneID.Value;
        MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        int readBytes = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        string tempFileName = "ABCD-" + 025-A-11-1+ ".jpg";
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        //request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://15R-75490.jpg");
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://025-A-11-1/still.jpg");
        request.Timeout = 8000;  //8000 Not work 
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        try
            {
               
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();


                do
                {
                    readBytes = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    MemoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                } while (readBytes > 0);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + tempFileName);
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";


                Response.BinaryWrite(MemoryStream.GetBuffer());
                Response.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();


            do
            {
                readBytes = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                MemoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            } while (readBytes > 0);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "imageNotAvail", "javascript:imageNotAvail();", true);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + tempFileName);
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";


            Response.BinaryWrite(MemoryStream.GetBuffer());
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please only use tags related to the question. This clearly has nothing to do with HTML, javascript or SQL Server. Adding tags that have nothing to do with the question is far more likely to attract downvotes than get your question "extra views". Especially as those watching the unrelated tags may well have no experience with the technologies the question is *really* about.

Comment: What happens if you enter your https://025-A-11-1/still.jpg into a browser?

Comment: its show me image